# Use v-select box inside v-radio option

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using v radio group for 3 particular options . One of them needs a v select box to select provided data. How can that be achieved using vuetify
[image: Just like this image]

Answer (score -1):

Probably by grouping them in a div something like:

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <!-- The <v-radio> -->
  <div style="display: flex">
    <input id="option1" type="radio" />
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
  </div>
  
  <!-- The <v-select> -->
  <select>
    <option>Hello</option>
  </select>
</div>
```